# Issue running expression in query for filtering

Tags: sql, ms-access

Essentially I have a simple Select Query on a Table called "myTable" that has the following expression in the criteria field:

```
IIf([Forms]![Home_Page]![CheckBox]=True,[myTable].[Customer_ID]<>500,[myTable].[Customer_ID])
```

What I am trying to do is if CheckBox is selected in the form Home_Page, exclude 500, otherwise show all records.

But for some reason when checkbox is selected I am getting no query results.

Is there a syntax error?

Comment: Yes there is. The equivalent operator (= and <> in this case) cannot be dynamic. I don't use dynamic parameters in queries. I prefer VBA to build filter and apply filter to form or report. Try: `WHERE Customer_ID <> IIf([Forms]![Home_Page]![CheckBox], 500, 0)`.

Comment: But in your example you're not referencing the state of the CheckBox? Where would that be placed?

Comment: It's not necessary. Checkbox value is either True or it's not. Comparing to True is not needed but if it helps you, go ahead and use it. The = sign I meant cannot be dynamic is the one implied in the False argument. Did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operators for field filter - logicals or equivalents (in this case, <> in the True argument and = as implied in the False argument) - cannot be dynamic.

Try: `WHERE Customer_ID <> IIf([Forms]![Home_Page]![CheckBox], 500, 0)`

Note the <> conditional operator for field filter is fixed but the value used for comparison is dynamic.

I don't use dynamic parameters in queries. I prefer VBA to build filter and apply filter to form or report.

Comment: This does not seem to work, now for both states of the checkbox I still get the full amount of records.

Comment: Are you able to get it to work as a dynamic parameter in query? In my case it would be much better to only use a query as I don't need to use forms or reports.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I tested.

Comment: So just to be sure we are on the same page. When checkbox is selected in the form I need to exclude 500 from the Customer_ID Field, otherwise show all records.

Comment: So if checkbox is True, exclude records with Customer_ID 500, otherwise show all. That's what I tested. Only my excluded ID was 3. When checkbox is True, records with 3 are not retrieved. This is an UNBOUND checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Using the query GUI, this works here:

[image]

Of course, replace 0 and -1 with *False* and *True* if you prefer so.